# How to do inverse pyramid while using while loop in python

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I need help in doing this. We need to create a code where the output must be the inverse of this code

Sample code(our basis):

```py
line = 1
while line <= 5:
    number = 1
    while number <= line:
        print(number, end = '')
        number = number + 1
    line = line + 1
    print('')
```

Output:

```
1
12
123
1234
12345
```

It must be:

```
12345
1234
123
12
1
```

May you help me?

Comment: Just count from 5 to 1 instead in your outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code

```
line = 5
while line >= 1:
number = 1
while number <= line:
    print(number, end = '')
    number = number + 1
line = line - 1
print('')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are several ways to write a pyramid.

Given the requirement to use `while`:

```py
from functools import reduce


def inverse_pyramid(lines: int) -> None:
    while lines:
        xs = reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y), range(1, lines + 1))
        print(xs)
        lines -= 1
```

How to without the use of loops:

```py
from functools import reduce


def recursive_inverse_pyramid(lines: int) -> None:
    if lines:
        xs = reduce(lambda x, y: str(x) + str(y), range(1, lines + 1))
        print(xs)
        recursive_inverse_pyramid(lines - 1)
```

How to with map instead of reduce:

```py
def pyramid_mapper(lines: int) -> None:
    if lines:
        xs = map(str, range(1, lines + 1))
        print(''.join(xs))
        pyramid_mapper(lines - 1)
```

How to with a comprehension:

```py
def pyramid_comprehension(lines: int) -> None:
    while lines:
        xs = (str(x) for x in range(1, lines + 1))
        print(''.join(xs))
        lines -= 1
```